# Postback of one dropdown fires selectedindexchanged event of all all remaining dropdown

Tags: asp.net

Example:

```
  <asp:DropDownList runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ID="ddlSample">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="text1" />
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="text2" />
                                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Now if change the item in the above dropdown it will cause all the other dropdowns postback events to fire.

Like

```
   <asp:DropDownList EnableViewState="true" ID="ddlNewSelec" runat="server" 
     AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlNewSelec_SelectedIndexChanged">
             <asp:ListItem Text="--Select Test Type--" Value="" />
   </asp:DropDownList>
```

Details:

The Page has **ViewState** disabled. I try enabling viewstate for the individual dropdowns but it does not matter.

Any idea why this is happeing.

Let me know if you need any more details

EDIT:

The dropdown fires the selectedindexchanged event of all other dropdowns on the form. The dropdown named as ddlSample is doing nothing just causing postback but why the selectedindexchanged evenet of other dropdowns fired up.

Additional Info:

All the inputs are in updatePanel and removing them does not make any effect.

In Page Load i am not doing anything on postback

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindSomeDDLs();
         }
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by **postback of all remaining dropdowns**? are you talking about page is posting back more than once?

Comment: Autopostback just wires up an onchange javascript event which submits the form, which happens to be the entire page. Looks like its working as intended.

Comment: @SanjeevRai Sorry, means it fires the selectedindexchanged event of all dropdowns on the form

Comment: @Phill Sorry, means it fires the selectedindexchanged event of all dropdowns on the form

Comment: you may be binding or selecting other dropdown's value from code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be very weird but this is true.

This is happening just because of EnableViewState property set to false.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't bind the SelectedIndexChanged event on the "ddlSample" dropdown.  Please try binding that property like so..

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSample" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSample_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="text1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="text2" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: I think my question is not very clear. This is a test dropdown that does not have any event attached to it. The problem is causing/changing the drodown will cause the selecting index of all other dropdowns on this page even their values are not changed at all. E.g We have 100 dropdown and changing any drodpown value cause the selectedchangeindex of all other dropdown

Comment: Then please update your question, with 2 valid dropdowns that trigger the selectedchangeindex. My second guess would be that you bound all dropdowns to the same OnSelectedIndexChanged event, but I can't confirm this without you posting more code.